# iOS button onClick failed due to unrecognized selector sent

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to develop a demo apps for iPhone displaying a label title and button.
When clicking the button, the alert message box is displayed.

When it comes to the implementation,it comes with the following exception. I have tried to make viewController and window to be global variables but to no avail.

Would you please tell me if there are alternatives or not to try to create the event handling for the UIButton

```
'-[UIViewController OnClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d7e1b0'
```

The below is my code

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


@synthesize titleLabel;
@synthesize clickButton;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    [self OnClick:clickButton];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)OnClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIAlertView *helloWorldAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"My First App" message:@"Hello, World!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    // Display the Hello World Message
    [helloWorldAlert show];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.clickButton = nil;
}
@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UILabel *titleLabel;
    UIButton *clickButton;

@public
    double frequency;
    double sampleRate;
    double theta;
}

@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UIButton *clickButton;

- (IBAction)OnClick:(UIButton *)clickButton;

@end
```

XIB.

Only having Object App Delegate
UI Items and View

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    ViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate


@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

// ... UIApplication Delegate methods
@end
```

Comment: Did you associate the function with any of UIButton events like TouchUpInside?

Comment: Check the connection inspector properly wheather u have connected the IBoulets properly or any undefined IBoulets connected

Comment: Have you connected your action with the respective button in the xib?

Comment: Recheck that the function is linked with with button via any of touch events.

Comment: Why are you calling that function in the `onMemoryWarning` method?

Comment: I have assigned method touchUpInside at this button to File's Owner but to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `didFinishLaunching`.  Where you allocate your view controller -

```
 UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

You are allocating the base `UIViewController`, which doesn't have your `clickButton` method - so you get the exception.  What you want is -

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

By omitting the UI you get an instance of your UIViewController subclass, which implements the `clickButton` method.

Comment: Nicely spotted. This is why it's best if one sticks to appropriate naming conventions, there's less probability of making spelling mistakes like that.

Comment: Excellent ! solved  ! Thanks. Does this suggested line can be used to redirect to other ViewControllers too ?

Comment: Yes, this is the general method to instantiate `UIViewController` subclasses from XIB files.  You won't do the `self.window.rootViewController = viewController;` typically, though.  You will present the new view controller or push it using a navigation controller etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create that object of controller class in which you define the method of button in `didFinishLaunching` method of `appDelegate` not `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you link the action with your `UIButton` ?

if not, place this in `viewDidLoad`

`[clickButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

and this of code should not be there

`[self OnClick:clickButton];`

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
  UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  [button setTitle:@"my button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.view addSubview:button];

}
```

Comment: you should watch some tutorial on Youtube about using `UIStoryboard`. However, you can do this will code only (i'm editing my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did not associate the UIButton in xib. code

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
    IBOutlet UIButton *clickButton;
}
```

And associate clickButton to your respective button in xib.

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement the `OnClick:` method in your implementation file. Like so:

In `ViewController.m`, add the following:

```
- (IBAction)OnClick:(UIButton *)clickButton
{
    // logic here, what to do when button was clicked!
}
```

Comment: doh, damn hidden scroll bars!